# Numeric value does not return as object htmltablerowelement

Tags: jquery

In the case scrollTop event, (scrollTo)value with string returns as [object htmltablerowelement] whereas (scrollTo)valuewith numeric returns as numeric itself. 
(scrollTo)value with string scroll top correctly, (scrollTo)value with numeric 
does not function properly.

kindly help to resolve

```
String stdNo = request.getAttribute("pValueAction").toString();         
<html>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr id='stdNo'>....</tr>
    </table>
</div>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var m = <%=stdNo%>,    
        container = $('div'),
        scrollTo = $(m);      
        alert(m);
        container.animate({
            scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
        });
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
String stdNo = request.getAttribute("pValueAction").toString();
```

Then assign the value to a hidden field as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidid" value=<%=stdNo%> >
```

Then you can call it using jquery into a vraiable as follows:

```
var m = $("#hidid").val();
```

and do your stuff.

This wont work  `var m = <%=stdNo%>`

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you Santhucool, but m returns as value instead of object htmltablerowelement

Comment: @jj2422 m will return value only because you are reading the value which get from jsp. Your question is not clear. Why you need object instead of value?